# Convert Access 2010 to older versions

Tags: ms-access, converters, ms-access-2010, backwards-compatibility

I want to be able to convert a Access 2010 database to multiple different older version by using a script

So if I feed a 2010 Access to the script I want it to spit out one of the following versions: 2000, 2002, 2003 or 2007.

How is this possible?

I'm not looking for a complete script, but more a pointer in the right direction or perhaps an example of how it can be done.

*** EDIT ***

```
TmpName = Destination & "\" & dbDisname & "_2002.mdb"
If Dir(TmpName) <> "" Then
   FS.deletefile TmpName
End If
objAccess.ConvertAccessProject strSourcePath & dbCurrent, TmpName, acFileFormatAccess2002
TextName = dbDisname & "_2002.mdb"
objAccess.Quit
```

Problem is that I get a "Run-time error '52': Bad file name or number"

But the paths are correct?

- strSourcePath & dbCurrent = "C:\new.accdb"
- TmpName = "C:\new_2002.mdb"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
ConvertAccessProject "z:\docs\test.accdb", _
         "z:\docs\test.mdb", acFileFormatAccess2000
```

You are likely to get all sorts of error messages, which I have not attempted to sort out, but you will end up with an Access 2000 mdb. other formats are available through intellisense.

Microsoft references:
[File format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195879%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
[ConvertAccessProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221163%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
[Some possible problems](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/convert-an-access-2007-database-to-an-earlier-file-format-HA010230822.aspx#BM1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I've updated the main post with more info.. could you please take a look? :)

Comment: You will not be allowed to wrote to the root, c:\, choose a directory with write permissions.

Comment: I've tried to set the path to c:\folder\dbname.mdb and set full permission.. but still I get the same error :/

Comment: None the less, I think this is a write error of some description. Substitute values for your variables and see if it runs. Also, why objAccess? You should be running from the current db and I seriously doubt that you should be converting an open database. Get the path of the db you wish to convert and refer to it as a string.

Comment: I got it working now :)

Although when I convert a accdb file to a Access 2002 version it opens MS Access up with the "Save as " window open.. 

I'm using this code: 
objAccess.ConvertAccessProject str, TmpName, AcFileFormat.acFileFormatAccess2002

Any idea why that might be?

Comment: No, I don't it works for me. However, you are using 'str' which is the name of a function for a variable name, this is a very bad idea indeed. I am still not sure why you are complicating the code.

Comment: The reason I'm "complicating" the code is that it will be a part of a bigger script which does some other processing to find the path for the database file. I also found out that the reason it sometimes opens MS Access is when you try to convert to the same version it already is.. e.g. 2002 -> 2002 = executes msaccess.exe

But thanks for your help.. my script is working just fine now :)